# Match a substring exactly in a table of strings

Tags: r

I have a table with many plant names, it looks like this:

```
|Parmelia sulcata, Xanthoria parietina, Lecanora muralis|
|Lecanora muralis var. saxicola, Lecanora hagenii|
```

I want to search a species in there e.g. Lecanora muralis (sp<-"Lecanora muralis").

Currently, I search through the table with a for-loop.

```
for(g in 1:nrow(table))
{  
  such_syn<-grep(sp,table[g,5])

  if(length(such_synspalte)>0)
  {
    syn<-table[g,5]

    selbe<-which(sp == syn)
    if (length(selbe)>0)
    {....................}
  }
}
```

I want to match  my species "Lecanora muralis" exactly.

I have tried:

With `grep` it will match row 1 (thats ok) and row 2 (thats not ok, because this is variable is saxicola)

I tried it with `which` but syn is a character looks like this

```
syn <- "Parmelia sulcata, Xanthoria parietina, Lecanora muralis"
```

and `which` doesn't work.

Then I tried it with `strsplit(syn,",")`

```
syn<-c("Parmelia sulcata" " Xanthoria parietina" " Lecanora muralis")
```

But there are spaces in there and so the problem begins again.

And I cannot remove the spaces with `gsub` because all strings are then together.

How can I match my species?

Comment: `grep` will do an exact match if you put a "$" at the end of the pattern.

Comment: @BondedDust That isn't quite correct, "$" matches the specified pattern at the end of a string. Using "^<pattern>$" will provide an exact match since "^" will force matching at the beginning of the string and "$" forces matching at the end of the string.

Comment: Right you are. Should have said that a terminal-$ would prevent matching the "variants" that the poster was wanting to exclude.

Comment: Is this "table" a "data frame", a "matrix", or a "data table"? What's special about column 5 in `table[g,5]`? Is that a column with a single character variable, being a comma-space separated string of species names?

Answer (score 1):

Split it on the comma, trim off the whitespace, do an equality test:

Test with variant:

```
> require(stringr) # install this handy string-processing package if you don't have it
> syn <- "Parmelia sulcata, Xanthoria parietina, Lecanora muralis var foo"
```

Doesn't match:

```
> any("Lecanora muralis" == str_trim(str_split(syn,",")[[1]]))
[1] FALSE
```

Without variant, returns TRUE:

```
> syn <- "Parmelia sulcata, Xanthoria parietina, Lecanora muralis"
> any("Lecanora muralis" == str_trim(str_split(syn,",")[[1]]))
[1] TRUE
```

Try with some spaces and extra stuff, still TRUE:

```
> syn <- "Parmelia sulcata, Xanthoria parietina, Lecanora muralis ,something else"
> any("Lecanora muralis" == str_trim(str_split(syn,",")[[1]]))
[1] TRUE
```

Write it as a function for neatness:

```
> exmatch = function(target, clist){any(target == str_trim(str_split(clist,",")[[1]]))}
> exmatch("Lecanora muralis", syn)
[1] TRUE
> exmatch("Lecanora muralis var foo", syn)
[1] FALSE
```

This also means that when you get a better answer here, make sure they call their function `exmatch` and you can replace the definition without having to rewrite all your code.